# Hibernate's AttributeAccessor and PropertyAccessor combo not working

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a scala project and I am using Hibernate for persistence. With entity mappings, I would like to use the standard scala getter/setter pairs so that I don't have to write the normal java getter/setter pairs.

Using `AccessType.FIELD` works. And I know that I can just use `@BeanProperty` for generating the bean methods. However, I would still like to know why my configuration is not working.

I am using hibernate 4.3.6.Final. Trying to make use of the [`@AttributeAccessor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/AttributeAccessor.html) annotation is not yielding any results. That is, Hibernate is defaulting to its own internal [`PropertyAccessor`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/property/PropertyAccessor.html) implementations. My Custom `PropertyAccessor` is not even getting called. I have been looking around for hours and it seems like Hibernate doesn't have support for this feature *anymore*. That really seems weird since the `AttributeAccessor` itself seems to be pretty recent addition to hibernate. Also, there is [this piece of documentation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/topical/accesstype/AccessType.adoc) from Steve Ebersole that tells me that I am going the right way.

I have tried out several combinations of `@org.hibernate.annotations.AccessType`, `org.hibernate.annotations.AttributeAccessor` and `@javax.persistence.Access`. For ex.

```
@AttributeAccessor("persistence.property.ScalaPropertyAccessor")
@org.hibernate.annotations.AccessType("persistence.property.ScalaPropertyAccessor")
class User {
    // ...
}
```

Also, there is an open issue at: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HCANN-48

I am not sure what is the status on this. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I should put an answer here just in case some poor lost soul like me stumbles up here.

That issue is still open and it has been open since Apr-2012. I am not putting any hopes on it getting resolved anytime soon. And yes, I have been considering to submit a patch that can resolve the issue. I haven't gotten around to it yet. I have looked around the source-code of hibernate and it looks like the entire code-base is in a kind of flux. The comments seem to indicate refactoring of a lot of things for the upcoming Hibernate 5.

However, that shouldn't stop us brave souls, right? Well, I managed to write a piece of code that allows me to use Hibernate with Scala with scala's own getter-setters, and even allows using `Option` types without a hitch.

I cannot really explain the whole thing here, since it involves hacking into the Hibernate source code and doing some load-time aspectj magic to make it work like I wanted it to.

Even though this might look like self promotion, here is the [link to the blog post](http://bhashitparikh.com/2014/10/28/hibernate-with-scala-options-with-less-pain.html) I wrote about the solution, and here is the [toy play framework project](https://github.com/Bhashit/better-hibernate-with-scala) that demonstrates the example.